# How to copy data from ng-model to a table created by stackable.js for small screens?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table :

```
<table id="stacktable-x">
  <tr><th>Product Name</th><th>Manufacturer</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="product in AddedProducts" ondblclick="window.location.href = 'details';">
                  <td><input ng-model="product.Name" type="text" </td>
                    <td><input ng-model="product.Manufacturer" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then I am calling `$('#stacktable-x').stacktable({ myClass: 'stacktable small-only' });`.

Problem is that copy of the table created by this call is not connected to the AngularJS model when it is displayed on a small screen.  How should I proceed?  Is there any easy way to copy data from the original to the one created by the `stackable.js`?

This issue is only valid for small screens.

Stackable.js source: http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js

Comment: Using the binding of Angular with you stacktable table will be painful... I recommend you to keep the CSS you are interested in from stacktable and to apply it to your table made by the "Angular way", it will be easier to set up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't.  Don't do it. It is like ironing your shirt using a basket ball. I do not recommend.